# Linear algebra invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on some linear algebra and I am really struggling to get a grasp on the following question. I tried to start it but I'm struggling to even understand the meaning of the question. If anybody could point me in the right direction for any of the parts it would be greatly appreciated.

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_A$ a matrix operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The image of $V$ under $T_A$ is the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$T_A(V)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n |y=T_A(x)\;for\;some\; x\in V\}$$
We say that $V$ is invariant under $T_A$ if $T_A(V)$ is a subset of $V$.

I am asked to prove that $T_A(V)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Then too compute $T_A(V)$ in the case where $n=2$, $V=Span\{(1,1)\}$ and $A=R_\frac\pi2$ (a
rotation by $\frac\pi2$ about the origin in an anticlockwise direction).

Prove that $null(A)$ is invariant under $T_A$

Finally, find all the invariant subspaces of $T_A$, in the case where $n=2$ and $A=R_\frac\pi2$

I know this is a lot to ask so any advice as to how to approach this problem would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take a $y_1\in T_A(V)$ and  $y_2\in T_A(V)$ such that $y_1=Av_1$, $y_2=Av_2$ for some $v_1,v_2 \in R^{N}$. Now for any two real constants $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$, can you prove $\alpha_1y_1+\alpha_2y_2$ is also in $T_A(V)$?. Convince yourself, this amounts to prove that $T_A(V)$ is a subspace.
- Rotation matrix for $\theta$ rotation counter clockwise in $2-D$ is given by 
  \begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
  -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
  In this case, your $V=span([1,1])$. Note that this is actually $y=x$ line in the $2-D$. The question asks you what happens when we rotate any point on this line by $\pi/2$. (I think there is some problem with the question, if you think more about it, you can figure that after rotation that point will never on the $y=x$ line again, except for origin. Think about what happens if $V=span([1,-1])$. For the $V$ in the question, think about a $\pi$ degree rotation.
- Let $x\in null(A)$, so $Ax=0$, now $0 \in V$, now think about it.
- $A$ in this case is nothing but $\pi/2$ degree rotation. $R^{2}$ and $null(A)$ are two trivial invariant spaces. I can't think of any other.

Comment: Just a comment for a last part: if an invariant subspace contains nonzero vector $v$, then $v$ and $Av$ are linear independent and thus spans the whole space.